# Plot a numerical values in United states map based on Abbreviated state names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data as below that has all the states. Providing a sample here,

```
state_name value_x
AL 250
AK 900
.
.

MT 1000
NJ 10000
.
WY 500
```

Now I need to plot these numbers(value_x) in US map according to state abbreviations.

I tried reading about this package `fiftystater` online. But i am not getting anywhere in plotting this.

I read this stackoverflow post too. But i don't know how to apply to to my specific dataset.

[How to map all the states of US using R with the number of crimes occurred in each state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859779/how-to-map-all-the-states-of-us-using-r-with-the-number-of-crimes-occurred-in-ea)

Please help! I want to visualize my graph something like this. I took this image from the stackoverflow post.

[image]

Comment: You need to get the latitude and longitude coordinates for each state

Comment: It helps if you can show us what you have tried/what the specific challenges are - see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is almost identical to the linked question except for the fact that your data does not have the lowercase state names already present.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fiftystater)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
```

Construct a sample dataset using built in datasets. You do not need to do this part, just call your values to plot `tbl`

```r
tbl <- state.x77 %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "state") %>%
  bind_cols(state_name = state.abb) %>%
  rename(value_x = Income) %>%
  select(state_name, value_x)
```

Create a table that relates state names to state abbreviations:

```r
state_abbs <- tibble(state = str_to_lower(state.name), abb = state.abb)
```

Use `left_join` to join the full state names to the data table that only has abbreviations:

```r
tbl_m <- left_join(tbl, state_abbs, by = c("state_name" = "abb")) %>%
  rename(id = state)
```

And then basically copy the example from `fiftystater` or [from the answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865009/7028459). Here the first key part is `geom_map`, which needs you to use option `map = fifty_states` where `fifty_states` is the data table from `fiftystater`, and also to supply `aes(map_id = id)` so that it knows which group of points corresponds to which values in the data. The second key part is `geom_text`, which adds the text you want at coordinates you specify. Here, we create a dataframe that makes the coordinates the mean of the lat or long for each state from `fifty_states`, and then join it to the data in `tbl_m`. The rest is just formatting!

```r
ggplot(tbl_m) +
  geom_map(map = fifty_states, aes(map_id = id, fill = value_x)) + 
  expand_limits(x = fifty_states$long, y = fifty_states$lat) +
  coord_map() +
  geom_text(
    data = fifty_states %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarise(lat = mean(c(max(lat), min(lat))),
                long = mean(c(max(long), min(long)))) %>%
      mutate(state = id) %>%
      left_join(tbl_m, by = c("state" = "id")),
    aes(x = long, y = lat, label = value_x )
    ) +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") + theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
                               panel.background = element_blank())
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you very much for the neat solution. I was getting this error when i tried load the "viridis" package. Error : object ‘cividis’ is not exported by 'namespace:viridisLite'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘viridis’. I googled and tried to fix the error. But it didn't work.  So i used "mapproj" package instead. And it worked fine. Thanks for taking time and explaining this approach :)

Comment: I noticed that my data also has "DC" (washington DC) listed as one of the states. But "DC" isn't a state and is not available in  fiftystater. But still I want to plot this. Is there any workaround to add DC to this plot?

Comment: Viridis is just a colour scale and not critical. For DC idk how you would expect to plot it because the area is so small; what would you want it to look like??

Comment: I have modified the plot such that it says the name of the state and value_x. I want DC to be included in it so that i don't miss any information.